# How to get proguard to obfuscate enum fields and methods

Tags: java, android, proguard

Say I have an enum like this:

```
enum Color { RED,BLUE,GREEN }
```

After using proguard, and then [`JADX`](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) to de-compile the source code, I noticed that the enums have been only partially obfuscated.

In the de-compiled code, I get something like this:

```
f.RED
```

How can I get also get the fields/constants and methods to be obfuscated too?

**EDIT!**

Don't think this is possible (for good reason), and *you* should **NOT** be trying to do this anyway.

Think about what would happen in the case of `Color.RED.name()` if `RED` had been obfuscated and you were expecting the `String` `RED`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't keep Color enum class and remove the -keep command from proguard file and the all the class will be obfuscated.

Answer (score -1):

I put this into my proguard-rules.pro

```
-ignorewarnings
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
-keepclasseswithmember class * {
    native <init>(android.content.Content, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```